# How to return the keys for three highest values in a nested list?

Tags: python

I am trying to get the keys for the most highest stock values. I only managed to return the ordered descending list of values. How can I return the keys for the three most highest stock prices?

```
stocks=['AMZN','CACC','EQIX','GOOG','ORLY','ULTA']
prices=[[100,120,125,90],[80,90,99,78],[60,90,56,16],[120,137,190,150],[30,40,80,140],[45,86,36,89]]

#first zip the lists
result = zip(stocks, prices)
#Error: zip object is not subscriptible, first convert the zip object to list, if we try result[
stock_price=list(result)


'''Output: [('AMZN', [100, 120, 125, 90]), ('CACC', [80, 90, 99, 78]),
('EQIX', [60, 90, 56, 16]), ('GOOG', [120, 137, 190, 150]), ('ORLY', [30, 40, 80, 140]), ('ULTA', [45, 86, 36, 89])]'''

print(stock_price)

#find the max of each stock
max_stock=[]
for key,value in stock_price:
    x=max(value)
    print(x)
    #append each max to max_stock
    max_stock.append(x)

#print max_stock
print(max_stock)
#sort the max_stock
x=sorted(max_stock)
#reverse the list, descending
y=x[::-1]
print(y)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sorted function takes two essential kw args, `key` and `reverse`. `key` tells the function what is your key for sorting, which in your case, if I understand you correctly, is the maximum value of the prizes, so if `x` is your tuple of label and prices, `max(x[1])` is your key. Adding `reverse=True` gives you the list in descending orders.

So the solution of your problem is simply written as:

```
sorted(zip(stocks,prices), reverse=True, key=lambda x: max(x[1]))[:3]
```

This returns the first three tuples. If you just want the lables, then create a new list out of this as:

```
[ t[0] for t in sorted(zip(stocks,prices), reverse=True, key=lambda x: max(x[1]))[:3] ]
```

or

```
[ label for label,_ in sorted(zip(stocks,prices), reverse=True, key=lambda x: max(x[1]))[:3] ]
```

Comment: What is x? I am not too familiar with lambda functions. It is a good one-liner, thanks!

Comment: x is the argument of the lambda function, in this case the tuple of label and prices. `lambda x:  max(x[1])` defines an anonymous function with argument `x` that returns `max(x[1])`